# How to create a stop watch in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stopwatch

I want to make a minute/second stopwatch that isn't very complex interms of code. I tried using the [Stopwatch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) class that returns it's current value when it's function is called, is there any way i can use the stopwatch class that will automatically update my text widget every second. I am using getx as a state manager.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Grid List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: MyTimer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTimer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTimerState createState() => _MyTimerState();
}

class _MyTimerState extends State<MyTimer> {
  final stopWatchClass = Stopwatch();

  @override
  void initState() {
    stopWatchClass.start();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(stopWatchClass.elapsedMilliseconds.toString());
  }
}
```

0 is written on the Text widget, but if u start the stopwatch a bit earlier, it shows the correct time elapsed. The problem is that i want the text widget to automatically update everytime a second has elapsed, somewhat like listening to the stopWatchClass.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet what you tried so far and what is going wrong as you expected ?

Comment: here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bw6zc1nncyA and https://github.com/bizz84/stopwatch-flutter/blob/master/lib/timer_page.dart